# How to list list element but hide paragraph and display only when the list element is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, css, list

I want display list first when clicking list element(e.g list 1) it should show up paragraph related to it
and when clicking another list element (e.g. list 2), it should again hide previous paragraph related to previous element and display paragraph related to this list element(list 2).
The paragraph could be in another div
Thank you in advance.

```
<div>
<ul>
<li class="servicelist">List 1</li>
<p class="servicepara">Paragraph of list 1</p>
<li class="servicelist">List 2</li>
<p class="servicepara">Paragraph of list 2</p>
<li class="servicelist">List 3</li>
<p class="servicepara">Paragraph of list 3</p>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The markup is invalid.

Comment: Might guide you http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/9N7nv/

Comment: @Robin, you need to correct markup first and then use jquery. please see updated answer

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar i have corrected it . it was typing mistake. Your answer is slightly not what i am looking for as in your example the paragraphs are not hiding when first viewing the page.

Comment: @Robin, please see already updated answer with demo on jsfiddle

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar..thanks it is working.. but can you help me with above. I just made few changes. like adding classes to p and li.

Comment: @Robin, please see updated answer for targeting specific <li> and <p>

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar  where is the updated answer. I just tried your link but i am getting same.

Comment: @Robin, click on Demo link at bottom of answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to correct your mark up as li and ul is not closed properly, see below html :

```
<div>
   <ul>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <p>Paragraph of list 1</p>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <p>Paragraph of list 2</p>
    <li>List 3</li>
    <p>Paragraph of list 3</p>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").hide();
  $("ul li").click(function(){
      $(this).siblings("p").hide();
      $(this).next().show();
  });
});
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/139/)

As said in updated Question, there are multiple divs.
So to target

```
<li class="servicelist">List 1</li>
<p class="servicepara">Paragraph of list 1</p>
```

You can use below code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("p.servicepara").hide();
      $("li.servicelist").click(function(){
          $(this).siblings("p.servicepara").hide();
          $(this).next().show();
      });
    });
```

Working [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/141/) for updated code

Comment: `The markup is invalid.` So you code will not work as intended

Comment: @Satpal, yes you are right .. it should be corrected first

Answer (score 2):

You need to try using jQuery

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li> List 1  <p>Paragraph of list 1</p>  </li>
  <li>List 2  <p>Paragraph of list 2</p> </li>
  <li>List 3<p>Paragraph of list 3</p></li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("p").hide();
$("li").click(function(){
  $("p").hide();
  $(this).children("p").show();  
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/junoyazi/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can, in many browsers, achieve this with CSS alone by (ab)using `<label>` and `<input>` elements along with the `:checked` selector.

Given the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><label for="li1">List 1</label><input type="checkbox" id="li1" />
            <p>Paragraph of list 1</p>
        </li>
        <li><label for="li2">List 2</label><input type="checkbox" id="li2" />
            <p>Paragraph of list 2</p>
        </li>
        <li><label for="li3">List 3</label><input type="checkbox" id="li3" />
            <p>Paragraph of list 3</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It's possible to show multiple `<p>` elements (using `<input type="checkbox" />`:

```
li input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

li p {
    display: none;
}

li input:checked ~ p {
    display: block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9QtGx/).

Or, using `<input type="radio" />`, it's possible to show only one (at most) `<p>` element:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><label for="li1">List 1</label><input name="pToggle" type="radio" id="li1" />
            <p>Paragraph of list 1</p>
        </li>
        <li><label for="li2">List 2</label><input name="pToggle" type="radio" id="li2" />
            <p>Paragraph of list 2</p>
        </li>
        <li><label for="li3">List 3</label><input name="pToggle" type="radio" id="li3" />
            <p>Paragraph of list 3</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

With the CSS:

```
li input[type=radio] {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

li p {
    display: none;
}

li input:checked ~ p {
    display: block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9QtGx/1/).

References:

- [`:checked` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked).
- [General-sibling (`~`) combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).

Comment: David Thomas Thank you for solution with js. But i would like know what about browsers. is it cross browser proof?